unattended-updates reports packages are being held back, but apt says everything is fine
I'm running unattended-upgrades and it is running fine, but for quite some time now the process is warning me that certain packages are being held back, e.g:
All upgrades installed
Package libdw1 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).
Package libelf1 is kept back because a related package is kept back or due to local apt_preferences(5).

So I Googled the problem, and found several guides to resolve this, but none of them seem to apply.
All updates install fine.
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
Hit:1 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:2 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [128 kB]
Hit:3 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://repo.netdata.cloud/repos/stable/ubuntu jammy/ InRelease
Get:5 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [129 kB]
Hit:6 http://repo.netdata.cloud/repos/repoconfig/ubuntu jammy/ InRelease
Fetched 257 kB in 1s (262 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Individually upgrading the packages doesn't help:
$ sudo apt upgrade libdw1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
libdw1 is already the newest version (0.186-1build1).
libdw1 set to manually installed.
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
$
$ sudo apt upgrade libelf1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
libelf1 is already the newest version (0.186-1build1).
libelf1 set to manually installed.
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Autoremove removes nothing:
$ sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Dist-upgrade, nothing:
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Full-upgrade, nothing:
$ sudo apt full-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Here is what apt policy has to say about them:
$ apt policy libdw1
libdw1:
  Installed: 0.186-1build1
  Candidate: 0.186-1build1
  Version table:
     0.188-1~bpo22.04.1 100
        100 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main amd64 Packages
 *** 0.186-1build1 500
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

$ apt policy libelf1
libelf1:
  Installed: 0.186-1build1
  Candidate: 0.186-1build1
  Version table:
     0.188-1~bpo22.04.1 100
        100 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main amd64 Packages
 *** 0.186-1build1 500
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

As suggested by Artur Meinild, I checked if packages were being held, but they are not accoording to apt-mark showhold which does not generate any output.
$ apt-mark showhold
$ sudo !!
sudo apt-mark showhold

I'm running into a dead end trying to find out why this is happening.

Please edit the question to show us the full output of apt policy <packagename> for both packages.

Done at the bottom of the question.

Are those packages held? Please include output of apt-mark showhold.

Nope, apt-mark showhold does not provided any output.

Does the Package libdw1 is kept back because... message occur every time? Or has it stopped?

It happens every time and I was unable to figure out why it was doing it, if (and what) I should do about it. Or if it was safe to ignore.

It's not an error, and there is nothing wrong.
You have the choice of ignoring the message (it's not an error) or acting upon it.
There are two things going on.

Your policy output shows that a newer version is available in jammy-backports
Current: 0.186-1build1
Newer: 0.188-1~bpo22.04.1
That newer (0.188) version is in jammy-backports. The "-backports" repo is NOT for security upgrades. Security upgrades are in a different repo.

The default settings of Unattended Upgrades are for security upgrades ONLY. It's a setting. You can change that.
On a stock install of Ubuntu, the new packages in jammy-backports WON'T be picked up by Unattended Upgrades because they are not security upgrades.
However, apt knows that the newer packages are available, so it notifies you in case you want to do something about it. That is the message you asked about.


Automatic install from -backports is discouraged. Their testing may be limited. After a trial, you might want to roll back. So it's best that you know which backports you just installed.

If you don't want to use the optional -backports repository at all, you can disable that repo, which will coincidentally eliminate the message.

Or if you want to install the -backports version, simply tell apt to do so:
sudo apt install <package_name>=<entire_version_string>
Example: sudo apt install libdw1=0.188-1~bpo22.04.1

Or you can safely ignore the message. It's informational, not an error.



Thanks for making clear this is not an error. I excluded -backports and now the messages stopped.
The reason I tought this was an error was because of the emphasis on FAILURE in the subject of the email:
[package on hold] unattended-upgrades result for xxx: FAILURE
